# How do I Authorize an Existing Iphone with New Cell Carrier/Provider?

Tags: iphone, iphone-x, activation, sim-card, carrier

Today my friend got a new simcard with Verizon and was recently with Sprint.

## Info

1. Old Carrier `Sprint`
2. New Carrier `Verizon`
3. The `IPhone` was previously under a lease but was *paid off*.
4. Signed up with `Verizon` and they gave him a new `simcard`.
5. On the day of him changing `simcards`, he was using `Sprint` on the phone an hour before this switching over to `Verizon`.
6. We Inserted the new `simcard` and went thru the setup process, but recieved an error

   > "Your iPhone could not be activated because the activation server is temporarily unavailable. Try connection your iPhone to iTunes to activate it, or try again in a couple of minutes. If this probelm persists, contact Apple Support at apple.com/support."
7. Tried using Itunes, and got the same error...
8. I was not able to get any successful help from Apple or Verizon.
9. [Phone was unlocked and compatible](https://www.whistleout.com/CellPhones/Guides/Will-my-iPhone-X-work-on-another-carrier)
10. Removed the `sim card`, and was able to get into the phone settings, I had "Reset All Network Settings", and the phone rebooted... Still the same issue.

Read articles [acknowledging the issue](https://9to5mac.com/2017/11/03/iphone-x-activation-issues/) but still no resolution in sight.

Answer (score 0):

## The long of the short

Anytime you change carriers with the new `Iphone`'s

1. Backup your phone in `Itunes`.
2. `Factory Reset` Your `Iphone`.
3. While the `Reset` starts, please change out your `simcard` to the new one.
4. During Setup Select Your `NEW` carrier. (This is only seen during a `Factory Reset`)
5. Connect to your `Wi-Fi`, as this is needed for `2FA` and `Apple` Authorization.

Then you are all set.

## TL; DR;

As for the detail.

This is a little different then the "Just [Google](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201328)  it" for answers.

I thought maybe he needs to setup his online `Verizon` Account first, since he was only at the store.  Maybe requiring him to setup the account first.
But trying to "Register" failed because it was asking for a `pin/password` that was not being accepted from his paperwork.

So, we called `Verizon` and verified his information.  Reset his pin.  Tried to register with the new pin, but then was prompted for the texted code, which was not able to be retrieved since his phone wasn't activated yet.

My friend verbally authorized me to speak to the agent on his behalf.
So, After 2 ½ on the phone. Found several items to note.

1. `Verizon` **MUST** `Authorize` your `IMEI` number to **your** account / phone number.

   1. Directions [how to get your IMIE here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204073) (International Mobile Equipment Identity)
2. We verified the new `simcard` id # with `Verizon`.

## The Kicker

Even after explaining what the issue was and what I had done, I was about to be kicked over to apple.  I wanted to try one last thing.

1. I `Factory Reset` the Iphone.

   1. One of the first questions you get asked is "What Is Your Carrier".
   2. **More importantly why didn't `Verizon` know to tell me THIS!?!**
   3. and why didn't the error message be more clear, knowing it is a new `simcard`.

Anyway... After that setup was a bit odd.

Apple hasn't recognized his new number during setup I had to:

1. Connect to `Wi-Fi`
2. Sign into his `Apple Account`.
3. Then after finalizing setup, his `Ipad`/`Imac` popped up with hey would you like to authorize `Imessage` with the new number.
4. Then ONLY AFTER the phone was activated could we create his `Verizon` account.

All in all the `Verizon` Customer Support was nice, but I ended up finding the solution that they didn't seem to know.  Provided the CS person with all the information, so they could document it but was painful.

### 4 Most Important Items

1. Make sure the `new provider` has `authorized` your phone's `IMIE` Number to your account.
2. `Factory Reset` your phone.
3. Then swap `simcards`
4. Connect to `Wi-Fi` for initial setup as the cell service will not work just yet.

Thanks for reading, I hope this helps someone...  As that was ridiculous, and could have been solved by proper instructions.